# How far into the future can a transaction be scheduled with `scheduled transaction`

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

in the documentation about the [scheduled transaction](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/schedule-transaction/create-a-schedule-transaction) there is no mention as to the limit (if any) to the value of the `expirationTime` parameter.

I have two questions:

1. what is the maximum value for the `expirationTime`?
2. is there a way to have the transaction be executed before the `expirationTime`?

thank you for your support